# Changing header color when scroll with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've tried searching for a solution for a while.

So it starts transparent and then as I scroll a certain length it changes to have a background color. The code below is what I have so far

CSS File

```
header {
padding-top: 10px;
background-color: transparent;
color: white;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1;
}

.changeColor {
background-color: rgba(30, 32, 35, 0.9);
}
```

JS in script tags at the bottom of the HTML file

```
 var scroll_distance = 100;
 var transparent = true;
 document.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
    if($(document).scrollTop() > scroll_distance ) {
        if(transparent) {
            transparent = false;
            $('header').removeClass('changeColor');
        }
     } else {
        if( !transparent ) {
            transparent = true;
            $('header').addClass('changeColor');
        }
      }
  });

  window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
    if($(document).scrollTop() > scroll_distance ) {
        if(transparent) {
            transparent = false;
            $('header').removeClass('changeColor');
        }
     } else {
        if( !transparent ) {
            transparent = true;
            $('header').addClass('changeColor');
        }
      }
  });
```

HTML file

```
<header id="headernavbar">
              ...
</header>
```

Any tips on how to go about doing this? I tried using JQuery as well but same results. It doesn't add the class at all. I also cleared cookies and cache before visiting the site and tried multiple browsers with no luck. I was also going to add transition effects after I fixed this issue.

Comment: Any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: No errors in the browser console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got it opposite. There's no error but the logic error.

- By default your background is already trasparent.
- You've set on scroll from top, to remove that class when its not even added.

**What you need to fix?**

When the `document_scrolltop > scroll_distance`, you **add the class**, else remove it.

```js
var scroll_distance = 100;
var transparent = true;
document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > scroll_distance) {
    if (transparent) {
      transparent = false;
      $('header').addClass('changeColor');
    }
  } else {
    if (!transparent) {
      transparent = true;
      $('header').removeClass('changeColor');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
header {
  padding-top: 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: black;
  position: fixed;
  border:2px solid;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.changeColor {
  background-color: rgba(30, 32, 35, 0.9);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="headernavbar">
  ...
</header>

RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANRANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>DOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>RANDOMSTUFF<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could simplify the code, you can see it working if you paste it in the console of the developer tools

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) { 
    let headerColor = (window.scrollY) > 100 ? 'red' : 'blue';
    console.log(headerColor);
});
```